# Why does powershell sometimes pass PSObject (instead of the base object) to .Net code?

Tags: .net, powershell, powershell-2.0

I am finding that in some circumstances, powershell 2.0 is passing Object[] arrays containing PSObjects - instead of the real contained types - when passed as a param to .Net code. I think this is a powershell 2.0 bug, but I can't find any mention of it.

```
$Source = @" 
public static class DotNetTypeInfo
{ 
    public static string TypeOfNthElement(object[] oa, int n)
    {
        return oa[n].GetType().ToString();
    }    
} 
"@ 
Add-Type -TypeDefinition $Source -Language CSharp  

$h = @{}
$h.foo = "bar"
#$h["foo"] = "bar" # uncomment this to fix! (Why?)

$testdata = @($h) # To .net, passed Object[] containing PSObject, not Hashtable!

# other examples that behave similarly badly - uncomment to try
$a = (1,2) # should result in an arry of System.Int32
function getA() { $a } # uncaptured value returned
function getB() { return $a } # explicit return
# $testdata = $a    # this works fine
# $testdata  = getA # also fine
# $testdata  = getB # To .net, passed Object[] containing PSObject, not Int32!

Write-Host "From powershell"
'  $testdata[0].GetType()         ' + $testdata[0].GetType().ToString()
Write-Host "From .Net"
'  TypeOfNthElement($testdata,0)  ' + [DotNetTypeInfo]::TypeOfNthElement($testdata,0)
```

This prints:

```
From powershell
  $testdata[0].GetType()         System.Collections.Hashtable
From .Net
  TypeOfNthElement($testdata,0)  System.Management.Automation.PSObject
```

The last line is very surprising; the C# code is receiving an `Object[]` containing `PSObject` instead of an `Object[]` containing `Hashtable`. This makes it impossible to use with existing .Net libraries that aren't expecting a PSObject.

Curiously, I can work around the problem if I use `$h["foo"] = "bar"` instead of `$h.foo = "bar"`.

I also see similar effects depending on how you return values from a function - uncomment the `getA` and `getB` examples to try.

By request - selected highlights from `$psversiontable`, edited for brevity:

```
Key   : CLRVersion, Value : 2.0.50727.5472
Key   : BuildVersion, Value : 6.1.7601.17514
Key   : PSVersion, Value : 2.0
Key   : PSCompatibleVersions, Value : {1.0, 2.0}
Key   : SerializationVersion, Value : 1.1.0.1
```

I can replicate this problem using powershell 2.0 on XP, Win7 and Windows Server 2008 R2

Comment: if you're still watching - can I get an explanation for the downvote?

Comment: I can't find whether PS 2 is still patched/maintained, but I've [submitted a bug report](https://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedback/details/817702/powershell-2-0-sometimes-passes-a-psobject-instead-of-its-base-object-to-net-code)

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code on a W2K3 Box with PowerShell V2.0, and the third test returned `["hello","world"]`.

I can receive you error if `getdata3` looks like :

```
function getdata3()
{
  $a
  return " "
}
```

So my conclusion is that you've got some "hidden" character in your script code, that was lost in the  copy/past to this question.

On more thing : Can you give the values of $psversiontable on your PowerShell ?

Comment: Do you look for hidden characters in the source ?

Comment: I've pasted it as is _from_ SO back into a script, same problem. So I don't have anything that you don't have here.

Comment: Your function should not raise that error either (there is no circular reference). I get the same problem as you with this function, and it goes away if I remove the `return` keyword. So I think you may have replicated the problem.

Comment: revamped the Q with lots of new info.